# How create port forwarding using SSHtunnelForwarder?

Tags: python, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to replicate: `ssh -i [KEY] -L [FROM_PORT]:localhost:[TO_PORT] ubuntu@[REMOTE_SERVER_IP]` in python and decided to use `sshtunnel` for it. The command given above works and I can connect to the remote Theia IDE, but I can't figure out how I need to configure `SSHtunnelForwarder` to achieve the same from within python. I am probably misunderstanding its documentation: https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel

EDIT: This code is faulty. Look for an answer below.

```
    # I replaced the remote-ip with `123.45.67.89`.
    # I replaced my ip with `987.65.43.21`.
    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ssh_address_or_host="123.45.67.89",  # ip of remote server
        ssh_pkey="PRIVATE_KEY", # I am unsure which one is needed tried both
        ssh_private_key="PRIVATE_KEY", # I am unsure which one is needed tried both
        ssh_username="ubuntu",  # username of remote server
        ssh_bind_address= ("127.0.0.1", 9191),  # where to listen locally
        remote_bind_address= ("127.0.0.1", 8181)  # where to send info coming to 22
        # ssh-port 22 (default port)
        # localhost:9191 -> 123.45.67.89:22 -> localhost:8181
        # which is basically 987.65.43.21:9191 -> 123.45.67.89:22 -> 123.45.67.89:8181
    ) as server:
        server.start()
```

But when I try to connect to `http://localhost:9191/` I receive unable to connect; so the tunneling is probably broken. I added plenty of comments to the code to make it easier to spot my misunderstanding.

Comment: do you get error when you run it in console/terminal?

Comment: when I Run your code then I see error `ValueError: You can't use both 'ssh_private_key' and 'ssh_pkey'. Please only use one of them`. And when I resolve this problem then I see another error `ValueError: Unknown arguments: {'ssh_bind_address': ('127.0.0.1', 9191)}` . Did you run this code in console/terminal to see errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code then I see error

```
ValueError: You can't use both 'ssh_private_key' and 'ssh_pkey'. Please only use one of them.
```

You have to use one of them and example in your link show what it should be.

```
ssh_pkey="/var/ssh/rsa_key",
```

or

```
ssh_private_key_password="secret",
```

It needs to generate file `rsa_key` using program [ssh-keygen](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/keygen) which should be installed with `ssh`

(on Linux I would keep this file in user's folder `~/.ssh`)

---

Next I see error

```
ValueError: Unknown arguments: {'ssh_bind_address': ('127.0.0.1', 9191)}
```

it has to be `local_bind_address` instead of `ssh_bind_address`.
Even example in your link uses `local_bind_address`.

You can see all arguments in commends in [source code](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.py#L484)
or using `help(SSHTunnelForwarder)` in code.

---

This code works for me:

I can use pair `username`, `password`

```
    ssh_username = "pi",
    ssh_password = "raspberry",
```

or pair `username` and standard file `id_rsa` with my keys

```
    ssh_username = "pi",
    ssh_pkey='/home/furas/.ssh/id_rsa',
```

Code:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import time

#import sshtunnel
#print('author :', sshtunnel.__author__)
#print('version:', sshtunnel.__version__)

#help(SSHTunnelForwarder)

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ssh_address_or_host = "192.168.1.29",  # Raspberry Pi in my network

    ssh_username = "pi",
    ssh_password = "raspberry",

    #ssh_username = "pi",
    #ssh_pkey='/home/furas/.ssh/id_rsa',  

    local_bind_address  = ("127.0.0.1", 9191),
    remote_bind_address = ("127.0.0.1", 8181)
) as server:
    print('Starting ...')
    server.start()

    print('Keep running ...')
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        
    #print('Stopping ...')
    #server.stop()
```

Comment: When writing "I tried both" above, I meant I tried both separately. I will try the solution tomorrow and will accept it if it works.

Comment: did you get error message when you run it in console/terminal? Show error in question. BTW: it needs `while True: time.sleep(1)` to keep running. If you don't use loop then it starts SSH and it finishs SSH at once - and you can't connect.

Comment: This works for me, too. My code above did run, but apparently I made some mistakes while retyping it in a more condensed way here. I actually tested it in ipython, but apparently even then it wasn't exactly the same. I'm sorry. Your code runs without issues.